# Can I use curl on c++

Tags: c++, curl

Iam searching on internet to use curl on C++ but it got more Confused

I use curl to send message from my telegram bot like this

`curl -F text="<My Text>" https://api.telegram.org/bot<Bot Token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<Chat id>`

Is there any way I can do the same thing in c++

Comment: I recommend [Curl for People](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run

```
curl -F text="<My Text>" https://api.telegram.org/bot<Bot Token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<Chat id> --libcurl example.c
```

This will generate a C code in the example.c that performs exactly  your request. You can use this example in your C++ code.

```
/********* Sample code generated by the curl command line tool **********
 * All curl_easy_setopt() options are documented at:
 * https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html
 ************************************************************************/
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURLcode ret;
  CURL *hnd;
  struct curl_httppost *post1;
  struct curl_httppost *postend;

  post1 = NULL;
  postend = NULL;
  curl_formadd(&post1, &postend,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "text",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "<My Text>",
               CURLFORM_END);

  hnd = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.telegram.org/bot<Bot Token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<Chat id>");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post1);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.55.1");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);

  /* Here is a list of options the curl code used that cannot get generated
     as source easily. You may select to either not use them or implement
     them yourself.

  CURLOPT_WRITEDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_INTERLEAVEDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_READDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_READFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_SEEKDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_STDERR set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_HEADERDATA set to a objectpointer

  */

  ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);

  curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
  hnd = NULL;
  curl_formfree(post1);
  post1 = NULL;

  return (int)ret;
}
/**** End of sample code ****/
```